# How to query jarray in jsonb field type?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

I have a jsonb field type in a table, it contains the JArray:

```
[
  {
    "code": "F01",
    "name": "Apple"
  },
  {
    "code": "F02",
    "name": "Orange"
  },
  {
    "code": "F03",
    "name": "Banana"
  }
]
```

I try to query based on the code and expecting the name like below:

**select a.myarray name from fruits a where a.myarray ->> 'code' = 'F02'**

but it returns empty

What I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
select j ->> 'name' 
from jsonb_array_elements(
'[
  {"code": "F01","name": "Apple"},
  {"code": "F02","name": "Orange"},
  {"code": "F03","name": "Banana"}
]'::jsonb) j
where j ->> 'code' = 'F02';
```

Replace the literal JSON text with the actual value.